# How to Position QR Code at the Top Right Corner of the Resume Header in LaTeX

Tags: latex, overleaf

I'm working on creating my resume in LaTeX using Overleaf, and I've run into a bit of a snag with positioning a QR code. I want to place this QR code at the top right corner of my resume, aligned with the header text, but despite my efforts, it either ends up overlapping with text or doesn't move all the way to the top right corner.

Here is a snippet of the LaTeX code I'm using for the header section:

*

```
**\begin{center}
    \textbf{\Huge \scshape XXXX XXXXX} \\ \vspace{1pt}
    \small XXX-XXX-XXXX $|$ \href{mailto:XXX@gmail.com}{XXX@gmail.com}$|$ 
    \href{https://www.linkedin.com/in/sara-khawaja/}{https://www.linkedin.com/in/s/}
    \adjustbox{valign=t,lap=\width+1.5cm}{
      \includegraphics[width=2cm]{frame.png}
    }
\end{center}**
```

- 

[Resume](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dZVPd.png)

Comment: Please don't post code fragments. Always include a compilable [mre].